# Del Command Not Executing Properly Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that I am uploading into Jupyter and I am trying to delete multiple columns at once. I thought the "DEL" command would be the best but I can't get it to work.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
% matplotlib inline

tmbd_movies = pd.read_csv('tmdb-movies.csv')

tmbd_movies.head()

del(tmbd_movies['imdb_id','homepage','tagline','keywords','overview'])
```

The goal was to remove the following columns:

```
imdb_id','homepage','tagline','keywords','overview
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
tmbd_movies.drop(['imdb_id','homepage','tagline','keywords','overview'], 'columns', inplace=True)
```